# Java SE 8: Minimal JSON webservice

Tags: java, json, web-services

I am trying to make a minimal JSON web service in Java 8. This is how I am trying to do it:

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

@WebService
public class DemoHttpServer {

    @WebMethod
    public double square(double num) {
        return num * num;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        String address = "http://192.168.2.66:8080/demo";
        Endpoint.publish(address, new DemoHttpServer());

        System.out.println("Service running at " + address);
        System.out.println("Type Ctrl+c to exit");

        Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }

}
```

But, when I hit the URL in my browser, I get `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`. Could anyone please tell me what am I missing? I don't want to use any external libraries for this.

Comment: if you hit `http://192.168.2.66:8080/demo?wsdl`, what do you get?

Comment: @yishaiz, Its quite a bit of XML. Can't paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write the exact url that got you the `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` error, but you say that your `wsdl` is working, so your WS should work.

You have a SOAP WebService, so you can use [soapui](http://www.soapui.org) or [postman](http://www.getpostman.com)(see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26530508/3883957)) in order to invoke your service (which is located at `http://192.168.2.66:8080/demo/DemoHttpServerService`).

You can also generate JAX-WS java client from a WSDL. In Eclipse for example there is a tool for that. For the real Java use for your WS, you should use this or something like it.

And lastly, you can write a simple program that calls your service, just for testing (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6594989/3883957)):

```
package another;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public interface IWebServiceTest {
    double square(double num);
}

package another;

import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = "http://192.168.2.66:8080/demo/DemoHttpServerService?wsdl";
        String namespace = "http://another/";
        QName serviceQN = new QName(namespace, "DemoHttpServerService");
        Service service = Service.create(new URL(url), serviceQN);

        String portName = "DemoHttpServerPort";
        QName portQN = new QName(namespace, portName);

        IWebServiceTest sample = service.getPort(portQN, IWebServiceTest.class);
        double result = sample.square(3);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Pay attention to the java package name when you try it on your project.